C# inserting a value at the end of the array befroe sending it through the serial port
I have a problem and need your help please. I have an array and a textbox, the user will enter a decimal value of maximum 32 bits in the textbox. This value needs to be added at the end of the array and sent via serial port as binary value, hence the var addressAndOpcode.
I am struggling because the textbox input is string, how can I do this please? Thanks
    private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen) 
        {
            byte[] payload= System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tBoxDataOut.Text);

            var addressAndOpcode = new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x08, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };

            // this is wrong it should be size of 4 bytes after position 5 which has value 0x03 
            addressAndOpcode[6] = payload; 

            try                    
            {
                serialPort1.Write(addressAndOpcode, 0, addressAndOpcode.length ??);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

I am expecting the following if the user types in 65535 (0xFFFF)
to be added at the end of the array before I can send it via the serial port
Like this:
{ 0x0A, 0x08, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00 };

Many thanks in advance.

You should use Buffer.BlockCopy to "merge" your arrays into the proper format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Buffer.BlockCopy)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue

If that makes it easier you can just do two serialPort1.Write() calls, one after the other.
